# Setup a MYSQL database on a Windows VPS for connecting outside network

Tags: mysql, connection, vps

I have a question about configuring or setting up a `MySQL` database for connecting outside my `Windows VPS`.
How do I need to configure my `VPS` for it and how do I need to configure the `MySQL` database?

Thanks in advance for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to connect to a MySQL server that is located on a VPS or other type of dedicated server then you most likely need to open the ports on the server.

The default MySQL port is 3306 and a guide to opening ports on a server can be found here: https://www.solvps.com/blog/how-to-open-ports-on-windows-server-vps-or-dedicated-server/

Answer (score 0):

To access MySQL databases outside your Windows VPS, you'll need to allow Remote Connection to MySQL Server. Probably, this tutorial should help you.

https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2200/How-to-Allow-Remote-Connection-to-MySQL-Server-in-Windows.html

Once MySQL server is configured for Remote Connections, open MySQL port 3306 from Windows firewall.